Why can't fractions be simplified separately within an expression
Here is a simple example:
$\frac{-x}{2}$ + $\frac{6}{2}$
Why can't I simplify $\frac{6}{2}$ here which would give me 3 for an answer.
The actual equation was y= $\frac{-x}{2}$ + $\frac{6}{2}$
I had to find the gradient and y-intercept of this linear equation in slope form.
If I dont simplify according to the rules, the gradient becomes $\frac{6}{2}$,why can't I simplify it inside the equation?
$\frac{6}{2}$ as an answer for the y-intercept clearly simplifies to 3 individually
Edit: the rule is that you have to take the least common multiple before you can even add/subtract them
Edit 2: okay I think my confusion lies in the fact that we need to take a common denominator before we can simplify the terms in a fraction within an expression

Not clear... $\frac 6 2$ is 3.

"If I dont simplify according to the rules, the gradient becomes 6/2" ... What does this mean? Specifically, what are "the rules" as you understand them? What do you get by following them? And how does not following them yield a gradient of 6/2? ... Perhaps you could work the problem out completely for us both ways, by "the rules" and not, so that we can see exactly what's different and advise you appropriately.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Saying $\frac62=3$ is neither dividing nor multiplying anything, so you're not breaking that rule; which is unclear anyway, what does it even mean to "divide or multiple a fraction"? Where does that rule come from?

You need a common denominator if you have the sum (or difference) of two fractions and you want to make a single fraction out of them. In the case where you are asked for a gradient and $y$-intercept you want two separate numbers (one is the gradient, the other is the $y$-intercept) so making the two fractions into one fraction is counterproductive. Just don't do it.

There is absolutely no problem. It may be formatting matters, like $-\frac{1}{2}x+3$. You may lose marks for not simplifying it in most examinations, but if it's an in school assessment you should follow what your teacher says.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"... you should follow what your teacher says" -- NO! you should grasp what she/he tells, otherwise ask until it is unambiguous and clear.
